# Ford focus Radio code

Tags: car, audio

I was doing some maintenance for my ford focus and i eventually took the battery out and the radio is now asking for an unlock code.Can someone help me with my ford focus radio code with the serial number M384762.

Comment: Try 1741 as the code.

Comment: Do you need help to find out what the code is? Or how to insert the code?

Answer (score -1):

Probably is very late, but **1741** is your code for M384762